# 'composer update' view commit messages for all versions to upgrade

Tags: git, composer-php

I currently use the `git commit` messages as a changelog for my private composer package, which is a shared bundle among some of my projects. I also use version management via `git tag`s.

Whenever I update this bundle in one of my projects, I run: `composer update me/mybundle`

This might upgrade the version e.g. from `v1.2.0` to `v1.2.3`. Sometimes there are manual actions required upon updating, which would be noted in the commit messages. It would come handy, to get a list of all commit messages since the current installed version (in this example `v1.2.0`). Something like this:

```
v1.2.1
bufixes;
v1.2.2
improved search;
[action required] updated Entities, run migration command!;
v1.2.3
improved post view;
```

Is it possible?

Edit: thanks to the comments, I found that you almost get what I need from github.com by going to `https://github.com/me/mybundle/compare/v1.2.1...v1.2.3` - the question still is how to get these commit messages automatically after calling `composer update`

Comment: This seems, as phrased, to be a question about composer rather than a question about Git (hence calling for some composer tag, rather than [tag:git], though I see someone else deleted [tag:composer-php]). If you want to know how to get log messages from Git, that would just be: *run `git log`*, perhaps with formatting options. If you want to limit the `git log` output to commits that come after some particular tag, you'd just need `--not <tag>` or the `^`-prefix syntax, e.g., `^v1.2.0`.

Comment: Thanks. Will try git. Would be nice to use composer directly though. Don't know why composer tag was removed ...

Comment: This might be interesting: https://packagist.org/packages/pyrech/composer-changelogs

Comment: Upon looking into `git log` I'm afraid git log should *not* work, afaik, as it would give the changes of the project, not of the bundle that is updated via composer.

Comment: @rob006 could you make a post and please elaborate a bit about the package? I will check it as the correct answer, as it is close. Cons: it does not show changes in the console but on github.com and for all packages updated. But overall it is close and great.

Comment: @ptmr.io I don't have anything to say about this package. Feel free to write your own answer with description how it fits your needs.